# Firebase as a single and shared main database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am thinking about building a marketplace platform with web and mobile clients. In plain english, think about it as a bad copy of ebay for a specific niche.

In order to simplify the backend side, I am considering using Firebase. But I am worried about the database.

Most of the documentation that I read about Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore is about small amount of data. With examples as a single user saving their data on the cloud, or a shared list of items shared among a few list of users (as a shopping list app...)

But in my case, this would be the main database of the platform, with all items that all the users are selling. Do you think that Firebase could deal with this scenario? a single and huge list of items to be shared among all the users of the platform?

Do you recommend any other alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Yes Firebase can handle big amount of data, but you need to learn how to do the data structure so when extracting data from the database you won't have to pass through all the nodes or it will take time to extract data.

Also Firebase is not only realtime-database, it also offers sending notifications, and storing files/images and authentication, etc.. All of this will help you in creating the application and making it easier for you.

Also check this link for the limitations in the database:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits